# Find top layers for a fine-tuned model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to use a fine-tuned model, based on MobileNetV2 (pre-trained on Keras). But I need to add top layers in order to classify my images into 2 classes. I would like to know how to choose the "architecture" of layers that I need ? 
In some examples, people use SVM Classifer or series of Dense layer with a specific number of neurons as top layers.

The following code (by default), it works :

```
        self.base_model = base_model
        x = self.base_model.output
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
        x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
        predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Is there any methodology to find the best solution ?

Comment: I think your solution is great, the real power lies within the pretrained model. 
2 or 3 `Dense` layers, just like you did, should be great.

Comment: Are they criteria on the number of neurons I've to choose ? (decrease the number, increase, ...)

Comment: This is parameter tuning, you must test and see. The answer from Chompakorn is actually better than  my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend either `Dropout` or `BatchNormalization`. Dense can be easily overfitted because it has too many parameters in a layer. Both layers can regularize the model well. `GlobalAveragePooling2D` is a good choice because it also acts like regularizer itself.

I'll also suggest that, for the binary classification problem, you can change the output layer to be `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` to predict only P(class1), where you can calculate P(class2) by 1-P(class1). The loss you should use in this case will be `binary_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is your advice to set a the parameter of Dropout ?

Comment: Do I use a GridSearch and choose the best ?

Comment: Changing the output layer like you said will really improve the accuracy of my neural network ? Can you tell me why ?

Comment: It will not be a guarantee improvement. First of all, you need to know that tuning hyperparameters are very difficult for deep learning, tons of researchers are working on this. Therefore, it is a matter of trial and error in most cases. However, you can look for other works related to you and adapt their model accordingly since their models were experimented and give good results.

Comment: Doing GridSearch is one of the approach to find the best hyperparameters, even Google do that  : ) (check EfficientNet for example). However, you should keep in mind that you are monitoring best validation performance, not training performance.

Comment: For Dropout, it depends on how many parameters you are using. Dropout is added because Dense layer got too many paramenters and might lead to overfitting. Thus, randomly shut down nodes can regularize network performance. I'll say selecting the appropriate dropout probability corresponded to number of Dense's hidden unit. If Dense unit is low, make sure you have a low dropout rate and vice versa. Tips, most dropout setting are around 0.1 to 0.5, no higher than that (you can know this fact by reading a lot of research papers).